# How to remove matching elements from one list using another? Python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel with two columns, like the following:

```
    A     B
0 apple  cool
1 juice  red
2 red
3 flag
4 cool
```

and I want to subtract B from A and get the resulting list:

```
    A     
0 apple 
1 juice 
3 flag
```

I'm trying to do it in excel or python. I wonder what's the best way to do it?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Too broad. What is your problem? Opening excel, copy pasting stuff?  Reading excel in python,do whatever you want and export excel again? Where is your [mre]? What did you research and try?

Comment: I imported the excel in python as a Dataframe, but got stuck at that step. Just made it work using @cgosalia's answer. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you would like to explain the idea behind how come `cool` - `apple` = `apple`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding of your question and the solution you are looking for. I think you should first figure out if you want to solve this in python or excel. Let's assume it is a list in python as shown below then you can execute that code. Please let us know more details so we can be specific with our answers.

Approach 1

```
list_a = ["apple", "juice", "red", "flag", "cool"]
list_b = ["red", "cool"]
result = []

for element in list_a:
    if element not in list_b:
        result.append(element)
print(result)
```

Approach 2

```
list_a = ["apple", "juice", "red", "flag", "cool"]
list_b = ["red", "cool"]
result = []

result = list(set(list_a) - set(list_b))
print(result)
```

In **Approach 1** i am looping through elements in `list_a` and making sure i only add the element to the resulting list if it does not occur in `list_b`

In **Approach 2** i am essentially doing the same thing but i am using a [SET](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) where i take a difference between the two lists. A set only allows unique values so it gets rid of duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

```
a = {0: 'apple', 1: 'juice', 2: 'red', 3: 'flag', 4: 'cool'}
set_a = {v for k, v in a.items()}
set_b = {'cool', 'red'}
c = set_a-set_b
result = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if v in c}
print(result)
```